# Geocoding Code not Working - Googlemaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, geocoding

I am trying to use geocoding to take an address, work out the longitude and latitude and then display an overlay on the map.

I am using the below code, however the log entry Log.e("Found",""+lat); never triggers and I'm not sure why. Can anybody help ?

Thanks !

```
private void showpins() throws IOException {

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);

    String Address = "Oxford Street, London";

    Log.e("Lat",""+Address);

        List<Address> foundAdresses = gc.getFromLocationName(Address, 5); //Search addresses

        int lat;
        int lon;

        for (int i = 0; i < foundAdresses.size(); ++i) {

            Address x = foundAdresses.get(i);
            lat = (int) x.getLatitude();
            lon = (int) x.getLongitude();

            Log.e("Found",""+lat);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    CustomizedItemOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
    new CustomizedItemOverlay(drawable, this);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = 
         new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "Location");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definite issues with this in certain emulator API levels. See [Issue 8816:    service not available](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816). For example API level 8 won't work. I find that API level 7 is OK if you call the method twice. The behaviour on real devices is not known to me. I don't think Google guarantee that the service will always be available.

Comment: Urg - what a pain - wonder if there are other alternatives and if it works on a real device.

Comment: There's a JSON work around, see comment 21 in the link. I've not tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

Either you address is not in Google maps address database or your app does not have internet access privileges.

1. Check in http://maps.google.com that the address is actually found.
2. That yor app has internet access privileges. You must have this in ypur app manifest:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```